# MS SQL 2005 Update records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Sorry if this is a daft question but I do not know my way around SQL very well. I have a customer table where I am looking to update the invoice address for each customer. I have imported the new invoice addresses in to a temporary table name InvAdd-Temp. Is there a way to cycle through all customer records and where the Customer Id equals the temporary table customer id it inserts the address details in to the customer table. I am guessing I need some kind of loop but do not know how to go about this. The code I have so far is;

```
UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[Customer]

SET [InvAddress1] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[InvAddress1]

  ,[InvAddress2] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[InvAddress2]
  ,[InvAddress3] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[InvAddress3]
  ,[InvTown] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[InvTown]
  ,[InvCounty] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[InvCounty]
  ,[InvPostCode] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[InvPostCode]
  ,[AccountNum] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[AccountNum]

WHERE [CustomerId] = [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp].[CustomerId]
```

With this I get the error below

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "Test.dbo.InvAdd-Temp.CustomerId" could not be bound.

Again, apologies if I am doing something daft but this is my first foray in to this.

Thanks for any help offered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but you need to JOIN the two tables. Try to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Cust
SET Cust.InvAddress1 = Temp.InvAddress1,
    Cust.InvAddress2 = Temp.InvAddress2,
    ...
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Customer] Cust INNER JOIN
    [Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp] Temp ON Cust.CustomerId = Temp.CustomerId
```

Note how you use the alias `Cust` to tell SQL Server which table should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try this:

```
UPDATE c 
    SET c.[InvAddress1] = t.[InvAddress1]
       ,c.[InvAddress2] = t.[InvAddress2]
       ,c.[InvAddress3] = t.[InvAddress3]
       ,c.[InvTown] = t.[InvTown]
       ,c.[InvCounty] = t.[InvCounty]
       ,c.[InvPostCode] = t.[InvPostCode]
       ,c.[AccountNum] = t.[AccountNum]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Customer] AS c
INNER JOIN Test].[dbo].[InvAdd-Temp] AS t ON t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

That should do the trick.

Good luck!